# can we use jpg images in iphone application

Tags: iphone, image, file-format

hiii frends,

actually i am working on an application which requires images such as for background, cars etc. png images are very heavy so can we use jpg images?

thanks for any reply.

Comment: Please mark my answer "accepted" if I answered your question.  Otherwise, let me know and I can go into more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**  [Easily.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW3)